# If Statement assistance needed for javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, if-statement, autocomplete

I am using autocomplete where each variable being searched has 3 attributes (label, id, value). I want the value of a users selection to be passed to one of four hidden fields based on the id of that selection.

js file

```
var destinations= [
        {value: "25",label: "USA",id: "1"},
        {value: "26",label: "Midwest",id: "2"},
        {value: "27",label: "Colorado",id: "3"},
        {value: "28",label: "Denver",id: "4"}
        ];

$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#destinations" ).autocomplete({
        minLength: 1,
        source: destinations,

        select: function( event, ui ) {
            $('#destinations').val( ui.item.label );
            $('#destinationid').val(ui.item.id);
            $('#destinationtype').val(ui.item.value);
            if ($("#destinationid").val() == 1){
            $("#results1").text($('#type1').val());
        }
        if ($("#destinationid").val() == 2){
            $("#results2").text($('#type2').val());
        }
        if ($("#destinationid").val() == 3){
            $("#results3").text($('#type3').val());
        }
        if ($("#destinationid").val() == 4){
            $("#results4").text($('#type4').val());
        }
    },

        focus: function( event, ui ) {
            $("#destinations").val( ui.item.label );
            return false;
        }
    });

});
```

In my html, I have the following: (i don't have them hidden for testing purposes.)

```
<input id="destinations" /> 
<input type="hidden" input id="type1" /> 
<input type="hidden" input id="type2" />
<input type="hidden" input id="type3" />
<input type="hidden" input id="type4" />
```

The autoselect is pulling the labels fine, but when i select one, it changes the selection to its value rather than keeping the label. It is also not putting the value in the corresponding text box and just leaving the value in the first text box.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Well i feel like its my js file that has something wrong with the logic.

Comment: OK, did i tag something as java and not javascript?

Comment: yup. You can check the revision history. I'll tag it to javascript. ;)

Comment: In the if statements, you shouldn't use "="; you need to use "==" for comparisons. Why do you have "input" as an attribute for each of your elements? And what is the variable "destinationid"? You don't declare it anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out thanks to Jason pointing me in the right direction. Its not perfect yet, but its doing what I want. http://jsfiddle.net/pkracer/RADGs/

Answer (score 1):

```
var destinations= [
        {value: "25",label: "USA",id: "1"},
        {value: "26",label: "Midwest",id: "2"},
        {value: "27",label: "Colorado",id: "3"},
        {value: "28",label: "Denver",id: "4"}
        ];



$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#destinations" ).autocomplete({
        minLength: 1,
        source: destinations,

        select: function( event, ui ) {
                $('#destinations').val( ui.item.label );
                var destinationId = u.item.id;
                $('#destinationvalue').val(ui.item.value);
                $('#type' + destinationId).val(ui.item.value);
        },

        focus: function( event, ui ) {
            $("#destinations").val( ui.item.label );
            return false;
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: I made the change using your first suggestion and still receive the same results. It changes the first box to the value and leave the other 4 text boxes blank.

Comment: If you want to update the value of the textbox to the id of what's chosen (or label), should you use $('#type1').val($("#destinationid").val())?  See my edit.

Comment: I edited but now i cant actually select an item from the autoselect hints to see if the other field populates. The hints appear but are not selectable.

Comment: Hey man, thanks for the help. I was able to get it working with a few tweaks to your code. Answered below.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="hidden" input id="type1" />
```

you got an extra "input" in your input tags... I'm not sure if you meant it was there on purpose for testing or what, but that would surely cause some unwanted behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Return false from inside your select statement, otherwise jquery UIs default select will be ran after yours.

Demo of working code: http://jsfiddle.net/FCw9f/

Comment: Hey, thanks for throwing that together but if I take away the hidden statements from the type 1-4 input, I don't see any values populating. Any ideas?